# How to select the first valid rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `pd.DataFrame` with time series as index:

```
                               a      b
2018-01-02 12:30:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
2018-01-02 13:45:00+00:00    NaN  232.0
2018-01-02 14:00:00+00:00  133.0  133.0
2018-01-02 14:15:00+00:00  134.0  134.0
```

I am interested in preserving the first non-NaN value of each columns and the rest of elements should be NaN

```
                               a      b
2018-01-02 12:30:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
2018-01-02 13:45:00+00:00    NaN  232.0
2018-01-02 14:00:00+00:00  133.0    NaN
2018-01-02 14:15:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
```

Does pandas/numpy have an operation to achieve this in a vectorized way (without writing for loops)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a boolean masking:

```
m1 = df.isna().cummin()  # get NAs prior to first non-NA
m2 = m1.shift(fill_value=False) # get first non-NA and after

out = df.where(m2&~m1)
```

output:

```
                               a      b
2018-01-02 12:30:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
2018-01-02 13:45:00+00:00    NaN  232.0
2018-01-02 14:00:00+00:00  133.0    NaN
2018-01-02 14:15:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `apply` `Series.first_valid_index` per column and mask the other rows with nan

```py
df[df.apply(lambda col: col.index != col.first_valid_index())] = np.nan
```

```
print(df)

                               a      b
2018-01-02 12:30:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
2018-01-02 13:45:00+00:00    NaN  132.0
2018-01-02 14:00:00+00:00  133.0    NaN
2018-01-02 14:15:00+00:00    NaN    NaN
```